# MySQL not connecting in QT application

Tags: mysql, qt, mingw32

I'm working on a database-driven QT project (basically a journal/diary tool) that will eventually allow users to connect with MySQL, SQLite, and Postgres. For now, only the MYSQL module is built, but i'm having problems making it work on Windows.

I'm compiling against a static-built QT 4.7.4  library on windows 7, and this allowed the program to find the QMYSQL driver properly. I know this because I'm not getting the "QMYSQL driver not loaded" error when I build everything staticly. However, when I try to connect to the database, I get "QSqlQuery::exec: database not open" errors. At first, I thought this was because the remote database wouldn't accept connections from my address, but I couldn't connect to localhost (as root, with the correct password) either.

I know the application code is good because it works perfectly on Linux (Same QT version, non-static build... it seemed to "just work" when built on Linux without any extra steps) so I'm wondering if QT is built correctly on Windows. I wrote a batch file to automate the build process:

```
TITLE Build QT 4.7.4 (static)    
ECHO ON

cd C:\qt-4.7.4\

path C:\MinGW\bin

configure.exe -opensource -platform win32-g++ -release -static -qt-sql-mysql -l mysql -I C:\include -L C:\lib   
PAUSE

mingw32-make

PAUSE
```

Am I building QT correctly on  Windows? When I first experienced this problem, I followed these instructions: http://rag.com.au/linux/qt4howto.html but it still wouldn't work after the most recent build.

I had to build QT staticly because without that my application couldn't find the QMySQL driver. At first, I tried using the includes/libraries from the MySQL 5.5 community edition, but the build failed about halfway through for some reason. (It didn't like something about that particular libmysql.lib) When I tried using the headers/libs I compiled against in Linux, the build finished properly, but I'm getting this problem now.

Does it matter where the Headers/Libraries are stored when QT is compiled?

Also, I have a triple-core CPU. During Windows build, I noticed that mingw32-make only used one core since my CPU was pegged at 33% the whole time. Is there a way to make it use the whole CPU so it won't take 4-5 hours to build?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Parallel building is at the make level.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533425/make-parallel-jobs-on-windows

Comment: When you open the connection (with QSqlDatabase::open), does `QSqlDatabase::lastError()` contains something ? Did you copy libmysql.dll in the executable directory ? Could you give the error(s) you get when you try to compile the Qt MySQL plugin dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the available drivers for you.

```
QSqlDatabase * db = new QSqlDatabase;
qDebug() << db->drivers();
```

This will give you the list of available drivers.

Check whether **"QMYSQL"** is there or not.

If it is not there, you'll have to install the driver.

Check [this link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-driver.html#qmysql) for the installation.

Comment: I eventually figured out this problem. I set up my system awhile back and I forgot that I was running 64 bit MySQL. Therefore, the MySQL libs were 64 bit as well. When I tried to compile against them to make 32-bit Qt, I obviously ran into problems. I installed 32-bit MySQL and compiled against it and everything worked fine.