# CMake / Ninja / MinGW Error

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw32, ninja

I need help with a cmake / ninja error I'm getting.  I am building on Windows 10 with MinGW gcc version 4.8.2.  I'm running Ninja 1.7.2 and CMake 3.0.1.  I was trying to change over from MinGW make to Ninja because make is painfully slow (single threaded only).  I tried to change over to Ninja using the following cmake command:  "cmake -G Ninja".  Then I try building with the following command: "ninja".  But, I get the following error:

```
FAILED: g++    -DPARASOFT_CPPTEST -DSIM_MSG_IMPORT_EXPORT -include cstdio -o0 -ggdb -I../ExtraUnitTestFiles -I../LCL -I../LCL/../../rail-tools/LDS_Monitor/win32-objects -I../LCL/LC_layer -I../LCL/IPC_layer -I../LCL/IPC_layer/Ethernet -I../LCL/IPC_layer/Serial -I../Framework -I../Framework/Enums -I../Framework/Core -I../Logging -I../Log_Manager -I../Messages -I../Messages/Common -I../Messages/AL_msgs -I../Messages/LA_msgs -I../Messages/Enums -I../Messages/Primitive_msgs -I../Messages/SL_msgs -I../Messages/AS_msgs -I../Messages/LCL_msgs -I../Messages/SA_msgs -I../Messages/AD_msgs -I../Messages/DA_msgs -I../Messages/TCC_msgs -I../Messages/AV_msgs -I../lib_ams/include -MMD -MT LCL/CMakeFiles/LCL.dir/LC_layer/comms_msg_pool.obj -MF LCL/CMakeFiles/LCL.dir/LC_layer/comms_msg_pool.obj.d -o LCL/CMakeFiles/LCL.dir/LC_layer/comms_msg_pool.obj -c ../LCL/LC_layer/comms_msg_pool.cpp
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: LCL/CMakeFiles/LCL.dir/LC_layer/comms_msg_pool.d: No such file or directory
```

Indeed there is no ".d" file present.  However, the "make" version does not produce .d files either.  I'm assuming that the .d file is a dependency file that is not getting generated.  Beyond that, I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: Did you clear the cmake cache files before you ran `cmake -G Ninja` ? For reference, "clearing" means deleting `CMakeCache.txt` and the `CMakeFiles` directory.

Comment: I deleted the entire CMakeFiles directory before I kicked off the build.

Comment: FYI, you should be able to get around `make -jN` issues with Cygwin / MingW, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533425/make-parallel-jobs-on-windows